# Chrome на Виндоус не открывается, но перечислен в tasklist, как исправить?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, task

OC: Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise

Мой google chrome высвечивается в консоли при запуске команды tasklist. Но при этом ни одного окна не открыто. И запустить через иконку его тоже не получается.

Существует батник, который иногда автоматически открывает браузер в моё отсутствие. Может ли это быть связано с проблемой?

**Дополнение**б Содержимое батника:

```
start "" [somesite_1]
timeout 60
taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq [somesite_1]"
start "" http://localhost:8083/
timeout 1
start "" http://localhost:8080/dashboard/db/marketing
EXIT
```

Comment: да, хром может висеть в процессах и при этом не иметь "окон". Но мало чего там в скрипте.

Comment: В чем может быть причина этого и как избежать этого? Я то могу кикнуть процесс, но другие юзеры этого не смогут.

Comment: Причина видимо в батнике.  Может не запускать хром?

Comment: При надобности я уберу батник. Но по возможности я бы хотел его оставить. Или хотя бы разбраться в проблеме, чтобы я больше таких косяков не писал

Comment: Мне не известно содержимое батника. Там может быть все что угодно. Я могу придумать несколько вариантов, которые приведут к подобному поведению и решение не в отказе от батника. Но так как Вы не рассказываете, что именно и как именно делает батник - самое простое решение - отказаться от батника.

Comment: Добавил содержание батника